# How to load script to dynamic model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a script to my view head part. Problem is when I load view I'm getting a console error "Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined". As I understand my script wasn't loaded. I just started working with .NET.ASP MVC.
Here is part of my view.cshtml

```
@model dynamic
@{
    var rUser = ViewBag.User as MyAplication.Model.User;
}
@section head {

    @if (!rUser.IsPremiumMember)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            myfunction
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" async="async" data-cfasync="false" src="https://script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" async="async" data-cfasync="false" src="https://otherscript.js"></script>
    }

}
```

Comment: If `https://script.js` is supposed to define `myfunction` on the global scope, shouldn't you be including this script **before** trying to use the function?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I already did try the different loading order but unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: So now the question becomes: does `https://script.js` really defines the function that you are trying to use? Also what happens if you remove the `async` flag from the script?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes, it is. I'm using it on different views and it is working without any problems.